# Password in Repository on Cloud Service

Tags: security, architecture, cloud

I recently signed up for a cloud hosting service that allows for one click application setup and updates using GIT. I created a WordPress application and pulled the code, only to realize that they used my account password as the database password (i.e. the password I used when registering for the service).

This was a bit unnerving. If I ever had my laptop stolen, or accessed without my knowing someone could easily destroy all the apps that I host using the service. When I asked the host about it, they claimed to use AES encryption (as opposed to password salts) and that the connection to the repositories is protected.

Is this a bad design? Is it reasonable never to store passwords in a GIT repo and to enforce salting on passwords? My only other experience is with Heroku where passwords are not included in config files (and my password has never shown up as plain text). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, the old "Don't worry, we use AES!" defense. If I understand your statement correctly, it would seem that they're storing their users' passwords unhashed in a single file then encrypting that file with AES. If so, then yes that's bad design generally. The standard method is of course storing hashed and salted passwords in an unencrypted file.

Storing passwords in an encrypted file suffers from a number of problems:

1) What is the password to the encrypted file? For "turtles-all-the-way-down" reasons, you can't encrypt that password. It can be stolen / guessed.

2) You have the standard password problem on the encrypted file. Do you make it low entropy and memorize it? Do you make it high entropy and store it on a disk somewhere. Both have obvious issues, and remember that this key is a single point of failure for the whole system.

3) Anytime their system needs to verify a password, it has to decrypt the file. So in all likelihood, both the file's encryption key and all the file's passwords will be loaded into memory on the server in plaintext.

As for the "They use my one password for both my overall account and my database access" problem, that's more debatable I think. On one hand you might want to limit how much access any one password gets you. But on the other, having to make a different password for every little thing leads to bad password creation and password reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. One comment is that I believe they are storing my password in their admin database using AES encryption. When I 'generate' a new application, they grab the password from their database and add it to the `config` file. I have access to all the source code through GIT (secured by ssh key).

Comment: If they're already using SSH keys for authentication in one system, then the ideal solution would just to be to use that for all authentication. They just store your public key anywhere and you can prove you know your private key using any number of protocols. If you do that, there's nothing on their server for a hacker to steal so that they could impersonate you.

I still don't see the point in duplicating your password around in these config files. If they have it stored somewhere, then just keep it there. It's probably just lazy programming.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to say that they shouldn't store passwords in a format that can be decrypted at all, instead prefering hashed and salted.

However, the problem here is that they need to access the GIT repository on your behalf.  Which means the password has to be decrypted by their servers at the time of use in order to pass it on to the other system.

In reality due to these requirements there is no real way to completely protect it.  Sure it's encrypted, however, that decryption key is available to someone that hacks the machine.

It really doesn't matter if you use different passwords or the same one.  If their site is hacked then the passwords can be exposed.

So, the real question isn't how are they encrypting it (doesn't really matter).  The real question is how are they monitoring the site in general to ensure it hasn't been hacked.  This boils down to whether they are using an IDS/IPS (Intrusion Detection/Protection System).  If they aren't, then move on to a different provider that is using one.

Comment: Hi Chris. Just to clarify, they are creating and managing the GIT repository (the password is added to a configuration file that is committed into the repo).

Comment: @Kevin Sylvestre: This part doesn't really matter.  If they have a system that has to connect to GIT in order to pull code then that system needs access to the appropriate password.  If the system has access to the password then it becomes vulnerable to a hacker.  This is a side effect of merging systems.

Comment: Correct, but the GIT repository creation and access doesn't use password authentication (instead using SSH key authentication). The password is committed into the repository so the web application is able to connect to the database server (i.e. it is a configuration file of the web application). What exactly do you mean by merging systems?